# Want a unicode character in django crispy strictbutton

Tags: django, unicode, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to get a chevron to be the value in a crispy strictbutton.   It should look like
this: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-down/

But, all I get is code in a little box:
[unicode in the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FNKY.png)

I've tried this:

```
def __unicode__(self, this_char):
        return u"%s" % this_char

StrictButton(self.__unicode__('\uF282'),
                            css_class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm",
                             id="button-id-right")
```

and this:

```
StrictButton('\uF282',
                            css_class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm",
                             id="button-id-right")
```

and get the same result.  I've tried embedding the html string hoping the browser would catch it - didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this by using HTML() instead of a StrictButton.  I'd still like to know how to do this instead of having to write out all the html.